# GeoNetwork 4.2.1 (Debian) install : error message

Tags: postgresql, java, geonetwork, tomcat

I work on a Linux Debian server. I downloaded the last war file v4.2.1. I pasted it into /var/lib/tomcat9/webapps. I have checked the permissions and i configured the postgresql DB. The GeoNetwork log is below. What could be wrong?

```
2022-11-16T12:04:32,245 WARN  [geonetwork.databasemigration] -   - Migration: Exception running migration for version: 4.2.1-0 subversion: SNAPSHOT. Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
2022-11-16T12:04:32,263 ERROR [jeeves] - JeevesContextLoaderListener: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/gn-domain-4.2.1-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/gn-domain-4.2.1-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342) ~[spring-beans-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar:5.2.20.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113) ~[spring-beans-5.2.20.RELEASE.jar:5.2.20.RELEASE]
        …
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_332]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
        at org.fao.geonet.DatabaseMigration.postProcessAfterInitialization(DatabaseMigration.java:122) ~[gn-web-app-4.2.1-0.jar:?]
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Connection reset
        at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgis.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.java:155) ~[postgis-jdbc-1.3.3.jar:?]
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:55) ~[commons-dbcp2-2.7.0.jar:2.7.0]

Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
      
Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Relais brisé (pipe) (Write failed)
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:111) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:155) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:81) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:355) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:267) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:262) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:138) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
                at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
                at 

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:141) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:464) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:165) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:109) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1397) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1305) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:440) ~[?:1.8.0_332]
        at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:41) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:571) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259) ~[postgresql-42.3.3.jar:42.3.3]
        at org.postgis.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.java:155) ~[postgis-jdbc-1.3.3.jar:?]

2022-11-16T12:04:32,284 FATAL [jeeves.engine] - Raised exception during init
2022-11-16T12:04:32,284 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Exception : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/gn-domain-4.2.1-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
2022-11-16T12:04:32,285 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Message   : Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/gn-domain-4.2.1-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
2022-11-16T12:04:32,288 FATAL [jeeves.engine] -    Stack     : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in URL [jar:file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/lib/gn-domain-4.2.1-0.jar!/config-spring-geonetwork.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jdbcDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
        at org.fao.geonet.DatabaseMigration.postProcessAfterInitialization(DatabaseMigration.java:122)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Connection reset
        at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.enableSSL(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:571)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:168)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:235)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:223)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:400)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:259)
        at org.postgis.DriverWrapper.connect(DriverWrapper.java:155)
        
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
        Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Relais brisé (pipe) (Write failed)

Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jdbcDataSource' defined in URL [file:/var/lib/tomcat9/webapps/geonetwork/WEB-INF/config-db/defaultJdbcDataSource.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:602)
.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
        ... 49 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
        at org.fao.geonet.DatabaseMigration.postProcessAfterInitialization(DatabaseMigration.java:122)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (SSL error: Connection reset)
        at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.BasicDataSource.createPoolableConnectionFactory(BasicDataSource.java:669)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: SSL error: Connection reset
        at org.postgresql.ssl.MakeSSL.convert(MakeSSL.java:43)


Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset
        at sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:127)
        Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Relais brisé (pipe) (Write failed)
                at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
        at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:210)
```

Comment: Possibly, the jdbc driver  wants to connect over SSL but there's no certificate or some problem with the certificate on the database server

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why jdbc driver wants to connect over ssl? With geonetwork, is it mandatory to use ssl protocol? According to you it would be possible to disable ssl connection attempt?

Comment: Driver may assume a cloud or remote database for production environments.  I commented because that is the behaviour now for Microsoft sql server driver; SSL is required by default, you can though override the requirement through the config